# UIAutomation in Xcode

Tags: javascript, ios, cocoa-touch, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I'm having serious deficiencies running a simple script to save my life!

I'm using the tutorial found [here](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/04/08/ios-automated-tests-with-uiautomation).

Essentially, there's a view with some elements and the code is to log out the elements on screen, via the following Javascript:

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var app = target.frontMostApp();
var window = app.mainWindow();
target.logElementTree();
```

The order of sequence I follow is:
1) Open example project
2) Command-I to open Instruments
3) Choose Automation
4) 'Add'/Create script above
5) Choose Target to the application

The script does not run. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get the script running from command line by creating a folder named 'output', and running the following script that can be made a shell script

```
tuneup/test_runner/run targetName fileName.js ./output/ --color
```

Comment: that solution was valid in Xcode 4, dunno if tuneup is supported for Xcode 5 yet